# How to find the average of two columns and having the average(output) in the third column

Tags: birt

How to find the average of two columns and having the average(output) in the third column

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
------------------------------- 
1        | 100      | 50.5  
1        | 15       | 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new Data-Cell and write the average function by yourself, because Birt supports the average only within one column and not across two columns.

[image: add data cell]

Add a data cell, set the type to decimal and write the average function. You can use the availible column bindings and add them with a double click to your function.

[image: write data function]